# VS Coded UI Tests: Making Window Titles Dynamic for Adding Controls

Tags: c#, user-interface, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests, page-title

I've been writing some coded UI tests for an item viewing page whose title changes based on what item you're viewing. This isn't a problem for playback, because the search and filter parameters have 'contain's options. However, when adding new controls to the map using the recorder, I've noticed that the search and filter properties aren't enough, and I seem to need to have the 'Window Titles' property contain the window title of the page I'm using to add the controls, or the controls will be added to a new window and document in the UI map.

Is there a way to make the window title property more dynamic so that my test team won't have to update the window titles list every time I'm adding a control from a different instance of the page?

Comment: I would recommend hand coding the controls.  You could then hook the name property to an event handler and update the name when needed.  Remember to use the AlwaysSearch configuration.  I doubt there's a built in way to accomplish what you want.  The auto-generated code is very limited, even for capturing controls.

Comment: If I have to I'll go to coding them manually, but for now adding them to the UI map and then using an xml tool to edit the UIMap.uitest in order to re-structure the hierarchy is a little bit quicker. Though, every day I care for the auto-generated code less and less. Thanks!